# Magento add dynamic text in Shipping Method Progress block in checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I want to show dynamic text into shipping method progress block
when I select something in shipping method it will show on progress block into shipping method.[image]

Comment: I have done this for one payment gateway, but nahi kav :D

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use event : checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method

And set your dynamic data into quote like :

```
$quote =  $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
$quote->setCustomData($request->getPost('set_data_you_want'));
$quote->save();
```

Then get your data from quote in below file like :

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$quote->getCustomData();
```

**{magento root path}** \app\design\frontend\ **{your package}** \ **{your theme}** \template\checkout\onepage\progress\shipping_method.phtml